# Replace content with next wordpress post (singular) with Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

When the user is on a post page (single.php) I want them to be able to click a next button and for the next post's content to replace the current content on the page using Ajax.

I've been looking around for a long time but all the plugins/instructions that I found were for loading more posts when browsing and not to load an individual post. What's the best way to go about doing this? Would really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You see, questions are indicated by a question mark (`?`), and your *post* has none.

Comment: Only looking for a long time or have tried any code yet ?